# Visual studio 2010: advanced project templates techniques

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Ok, i already know how to create a new project template using export template feature from visual studio 2010. Now, what I'd like to know is how can I create an item or add a reference to an dll dynamically based on user selected option in wizard interface.

I know that is possible to use conditional and loops within visual studio project template, but how can I change the output project?